# How to deploy web app developed with Dash and run it locally?

Tags: python, docker, flask, web-deployment, plotly-dash

I finished developed my web app using Dash (Plotly), and I want to deploy the app. I tried deploy the app to Heroku with Dockerfile, but there seems to be problem of memory (the app consume too much memory).

So I have 2 options:

1. Try understanding how to optimize the memory consume of the app
2. Deploy the app locally, meaning the user will install in some way the app, and then just run it and the app will run locally on his machine. This is the prefer option.

Do you have any idea how can I achieve the goal of option 2, considering I already have the app and Dockerfile?